# Why can't Scala find org.apache.commons.lang package?

Tags: scala, apache-commons, sbt

I want to use [org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html) as it seems to be the only NotImplementedException implementation in Java/Scala domain. I can remember I used to use it with Scala 2.8.1 with no hacks. But now it says "object lang is not a member of package org.apache.commons". Where has org.apache.commons.lang gone?

Comment: @matt-ball, yes, I do. Found it. Will answer myself so that others could see the answer may they meet the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just found the answer myself. The problem is Apache Commons 3 no longer include `lang` (including lang3 instead, which is differend and doesn't contain `NotImplementedException`), so we need Apache Commons 2.6. And what's inobvious here is that the Maven group id for it is not  `org.apache.commons`, but `commons-lang` - the same as its artifact id.

So I had to add `"commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"` dependency and do sbt update to make it work.