# Scalac compains "object lang is not a member of package org.apache.commons"

Tags: java, scala, classpath, gatling

I'm trying to add Apache commons-lang to my Gatling project (a load-testing tool written in Scala). I dropped the jar into Gatling's `lib/` directory, which gets added to the classpath, but I'm still getting the following compile error from my import statements:

```
object lang is not a member of package org.apache.commons
```

The code throwing the error:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
```

The last couple lines of the run script:

```
CLASSPATH="$GATLING_HOME/lib/*:$GATLING_CONF:$GATLING_HOME/user-files:${JAVA_CLASSPATH}"

java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH io.gatling.app.Gatling "$@"
```

What am I missing? Every other jar in the `lib/` directory gets loaded fine.

Comment: maybe related to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745693/why-cant-scala-find-org-apache-commons-lang-package

Comment: As if that didn't show up in the sidebar. Exactly my problem.